# google colaboratory: Failed to execute cell

Tags: google-colaboratory

Recently, I tried to use google colaboratory free GPU to try some new things. I followed https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d tutorial to set up my first code notebook.
But after I Run these codes first in order to install the necessary libraries and perform authorization

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools

!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null

!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null

!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse

from google.colab import auth

auth.authenticate_user()

from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

import getpass

!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL

vcode = getpass.getpass()

!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

when I copy verification code and paste it to text box, then every things become weird. I can't run execute cell and get the following message:

**Error**

> **Failed to execute cell. Could not send execute message to runtime: Error: Not connected to a runtime.**

Detail:

```
Not connected to a runtime.
eM@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_20180307_085323-RC00_188182835:2574:310

bM/<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_20180307_085323-RC00_188182835:1903:489

mg/e.child</e.onFulfilled<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_20180307_085323-RC00_188182835:640:214

wg@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_20180307_085323-RC00_188182835:644:292

sg@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_20180307_085323-RC00_188182835:644:164

ag.prototype.executeCallbacks_@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_20180307_085323-RC00_188182835:643:359

Xf@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab_20180307_085323-RC00_188182835:634:564
```

I tried to reload the page or relaunch the google drive, but nothing help. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score -1):

What is it you are trying to do exactly? If you are just trying to attach google drive to your google colab instance, you only need to run two lines of code:

```
  from google.colab import drive
  drive.mount('/content/foo_directory')
```